# GitHub Actions job name based on matrix index instead of matrix value

Tags: github-actions

I'm using GitHub Actions to run a workflow using a [matrix strategy](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategymatrix), as follows (simplified):

```
name: Functional Tests
...
jobs:
  functional:
    ...
    strategy:
      matrix:
        range:
          - -e FT_FROM_IX=0 -e FT_TO_IX=300
          - -e FT_FROM_IX=301 -e FT_TO_IX=600
          - -e FT_FROM_IX=601 -e FT_TO_IX=900
          - -e FT_FROM_IX=901 -e FT_TO_IX=1200
          - -e FT_FROM_IX=1201

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run functional test
        run: |
          docker run  --network host -t --rm ${{ matrix.range }} -v $(pwd):/opt/fiware-orion ${{ env.TEST_IMAGE_NAME }} build -miqts functional
```

It works fine, but I get a ugly description at GitHub because the `matrix.range` value appears as part of the job name:

[image]

I would like to have my jobs numbered (e.g. functional-1, functional-2, etc.). Is that possible using some expression to get the index of the matrix element (something like `${{ matrix.range.index }}`) or any other way?

Comment: Hey @fgalan, any luck?

Comment: I'm afraid no luck so far :( It would be great if GitHub staff could have a look to this post and tell something :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar use case, found a simple solution:

1. Change matrix range to a list of objects, containing `order` and `range`.
2. Concatenate `order` with the job's `name` key.
3. Use `range` key as before.

Hopefully, Github Actions will add an index to the matrix jobs, simplifying the way we distinguish between them.

```yaml
name: Functional Tests
...
jobs:
  functional:
    name: functional - ${{ matrix.payload.order }}
    ...
    strategy:
      matrix:
        payload:
          - { order: 1, range: '-e FT_FROM_IX=0 -e FT_TO_IX=300' }
          - { order: 2, range: '-e FT_FROM_IX=301 -e FT_TO_IX=600' }
          - { order: 3, range: '-e FT_FROM_IX=601 -e FT_TO_IX=900' }
          ...

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Run functional test
        run: |
          docker run  --network host -t --rm ${{ matrix.payload.range }} -v $(pwd):/opt/fiware-orion ${{ env.TEST_IMAGE_NAME }} build -miqts functional
```

Comment: Thanks! It works nicely :) As additional information, order could be also a non-numeric field, i.e. `order: 'f1'`

Comment: Yes, order can be anything, happy that helped!